# return pair of values instead of one value from two queries

Tags: sql

I've got two queries that return single result. 
They look something like this

```
// query 1
SELECT A.id FROM tableA A
    INNER JOIN tableB B
        ON B.id = A.id
WHERE b.status = 'ACTIVE'   

// query 2
SELECT C.id FROM tableC C
WHERE c.status = 'ACTIVE'
```

How to combine them and make return the pair of values instead of one value from different queries? I mean to get something like `[A.id, C.id]`

Currently I have to use two queries in the applications and I want to combine them into one.

Comment: Making this 2 query as sub query? Is there any relationship between them?

Comment: Specify the current results, and also the combination..

Comment: @Lee the problem is that they are not connected at all - like different tables and so on

Comment: @user1432980.. because if the result for each table is more than one.. it might double up the record count after joining them together

Comment: @Lee there possible only single result without exceptions

Comment: Provide an example of you current output. Explain how you combine the tesults now. What happens if the 2 queries produce a different number of rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question is not clear, so i assume that you either need`ids` from mentioned queries in one row or in different rows, you can use `union all/union` (provided that datatypes are compatible or implicitly convertible and duplicates or allowed or not) as below.

Combining Result in different rows.

```
SELECT A.id 
FROM tableA A
INNER JOIN tableB B
ON B.id = A.id
WHERE b.status = 'ACTIVE'   

union all

SELECT C.id 
FROM tableC C
WHERE c.status = 'ACTIVE'
```

Combining Result in Single Row.

```
select max(id1), max(id2)
from(
    SELECT A.id as id1, NULL as id2
    FROM tableA A
    INNER JOIN tableB B
    ON B.id = A.id
    WHERE b.status = 'ACTIVE'   

    union all

    SELECT NULL, C.id 
    FROM tableC C
    WHERE c.status = 'ACTIVE' 
    ) t;
```

**[SAMPLE DEMO](http://rextester.com/YBDY40685)**

Answer (score 2):

I think like this will do

```
SELECT (SELECT A.id FROM tableA A
         INNER JOIN tableB B
         ON B.id = A.id
         WHERE b.status = 'ACTIVE'   
       ) as 'query1',
       (
         SELECT C.id FROM tableC C
         WHERE c.status = 'ACTIVE'
       ) as 'query2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run following query which work fine for me:

```
select t1.id as aid ,t2.id as cid
from (
       SELECT A.id 
       FROM tableA A
       INNER JOIN tableB B ON B.id = A.id
       WHERE b.status = 'ACTIVE'
     ) t1 
full outer join (
      SELECT C.id 
      FROM tableC C
      WHERE c.status = 'ACTIVE'
) t2  on t1.id=t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join your second query with your first query as follows, so that you will get two (A.id, C.id) values in one query...

`SELECT A.ID,C.ID FROM 
(SELECT A.ID FROM table_A A INNER JOIN 
table_B B ON A.ID=B.ID WHERE B.STATUS='A')A 
INNER JOIN table_c C 
ON C.ID=A.ID WHERE C.STATUS='A';`